# center text vertically with css on jsfiddle

Tags: css, html, center, vertical-alignment

On my jsfiddle, I actually have a text on top when mouse is over images. I would like to know how can I center this text vertically with css. 
here is my jsfiddle -> [www.jsfiddle.net/kodjoe/4kurw7ap/](http://www.jsfiddle.net/kodjoe/4kurw7ap/)

I know that I've to use display:inline-block with vertical-align:middle, but nothing change ;-/ perhaps I've forgotten something ??

HERE IS MY **UDAPTED** CODE:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper"><div id="list">





<div alt="text here" class="item"><img class="imggrid" src="http://s5.favim.com/orig/141028/coffee-fashion-girl-grunge-Favim.com-2187377.jpg" alt=""></div>

<div alt="text here" class="item"><img class="imggrid" src="http://images0.chictopia.com/photos/highglossfashion/5948104335/high-gloss-fashion-dress_400.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div></div>
```

**UDAPTED CSS:**

```
body { background: #f1f1f1; }


#wrapper { max-width: 1260px; margin: 0 auto; }

#list {
overflow: hidden;
margin-bottom: -30px; 
-webkit-column-count: 3;
-webkit-column-gap: 30px;
-webkit-column-fill: auto;
-moz-column-count: 3;
-moz-column-gap: 30px;
-moz-column-fill: auto;
column-count: 3;
column-gap: 30px;
column-fill: auto;
}


.imggrid { width:100%; padding:10px;}

.imggrid:hover{ opacity: 0.9; }


.item { vertical-align: top; display: inline; margin-bottom: 30px; -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; -moz-column-break-inside: avoid; column-break-inside: avoid; }

@media only screen and ( max-width: 1024px ) {
#wrapper { max-width: 860px; margin: 0 auto; }
#list { -webkit-column-count: 2; -webkit-column-gap: 15px; -moz-column-count: 2; -moz-column-gap: 15px; column-count: 2; column-gap: 15px; }
.item { margin: 0px auto 15px auto;}
}


@media only screen and ( max-width: 600px ){ 
#wrapper { max-width: 440px; margin: 0 auto; }
#list { -webkit-column-count: auto; -moz-column-count: auto; column-count: auto; } 

}

div { position:relative; display:inline-block; }

div:after {
    content: attr(alt);
    height:80%;
    width:80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:10%;
    left:10%;
    background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    text-align:center;
    color:black;
    display:inline-block;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    opacity:0;
    transition: 0.4s all;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s all;  
    -moz-transition: 0.4s all;
}

div:hover:after { opacity:1; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Try this one:

```
 div { position:relative; display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; }
.centerDiv{
position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
}
.container
{
    text-align:center;
}
.centerDiv {
    content: attr(alt);
    height:80%;
    width:80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:10%;
    left:10%;
    background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);

    text-align:center;
    color:black;
    display:inline-block;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    opacity:0;
    transition: 0.4s all;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s all;  
    -moz-transition: 0.4s all;
}
.centerDiv:hover { opacity:1; }

.content{
 top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
    position:relative;
}
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/srLw8u0o/5/)

Comment: the text isn't centered vertically but i'll take this code. I can't put style for the text inside alt="" ??

Comment: just a minutes sir @fatyfatoumata

Comment: Check it sir @fatyfatoumata

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89033/discussion-between-ivin-raj-and-faty-fatoumata).

Answer (score 0):

Could you use something like this?

**Codepen** http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/WQvOYX?editors=110

All I've done is added the classes `first-img` & `second-img` and added padding to `:after` on the top of each one adjusted based on the image height.

I've actually never seen alt text used on a div like that i think it would probably be better to put the `img` and a `p` tag inside a `div` add `position:relative;` on the div and `position:absolute` on the `p` tag, it might be easier for you to work with.

here is some documentation on it https://css-tricks.com/design-considerations-text-images/

Comment: in this case the image height and the amount of text is not known hence i think statically using padding won't be a good idea

Answer (score 0):

Include `padding-top` for `div:after`

```
div:after {
    padding-top:33%;

}
```

Comment: we haven't a static height, so i think it'll be difficult to center it with padding !!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

Add the following code in CSS.
**CSS**

```
#box{    
    text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
   line-height: 80px; /*The same as your div height*/
     }
```

Add the following code in div tag.

**div tag**

```
<div alt="text here"  ID="box">
```

Comment: my div height is 80% !! how can i do with % height ?

Comment: in this case the image height and the amount of text is not known hence i think statically using line-height will not solve.

Answer (score 0):

Use a flexbox and center vertically using `justify-content` and horizontally using `align-items`. In this way the text can be more the one line, and we don't need to know the height of the `::after` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srLw8u0o/)):

```
div::after {
    display:flex; /** don't forget to remove the display: inline-block **/
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10%; /** not necessary but looks better with long text  **/

    content: attr(alt);
    height:80%;
    width:80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:10%;
    left:10%;
    background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    color:black;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    opacity:0;
    transition: 0.4s all;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s all;  
    -moz-transition: 0.4s all;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend solving this using some child elements. http://jsfiddle.net/4kurw7ap/1/

```css
div { position:relative; display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; }
.centeredDiv{
position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
}
.container
{
    text-align:center;
}
.centeredDiv {
    content: attr(alt);
    height:80%;
    width:80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:10%;
    left:10%;
    background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);

    text-align:center;
    color:black;
    display:inline-block;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    opacity:0;
    transition: 0.4s all;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s all;  
    -moz-transition: 0.4s all;
}
.centeredDiv:hover { opacity:1; }

.content{
 top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
    position:relative;
}
}
```

```html
<div alt="text here">
    <div class="centeredDiv">
         <div class="content">text here</div>
    </div>
    <img src="http://s5.favim.com/orig/141028/coffee-fashion-girl-grunge-Favim.com-2187377.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="container" alt="text here">
    <div class="centeredDiv">
        <div class="content">text here</div>
    </div>
    <img src="http://images0.chictopia.com/photos/highglossfashion/5948104335/high-gloss-fashion-dress_400.jpg" />
    
</div>
```

```
div { position:relative; display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; }
.centeredDiv{
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:50%;
}
.container
{
text-align:center;
}
.centeredDiv {
content: attr(alt);
height:80%;
width:80%;
margin: 0 auto;
position:absolute;
top:10%;
left:10%;
background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);

text-align:center;
color:black;
display:inline-block;
box-sizing:border-box;
opacity:0;
transition: 0.4s all;
-webkit-transition: 0.4s all;  
-moz-transition: 0.4s all;
 }
  .centeredDiv:hover { opacity:1; }

  .content{
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
    position:relative;
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using

```
div::after {
   line-height: 20em;
   ....
}
```